# VoIP registration is not done when Incoming call arrives?

Tags: ios, call, voip, registration, pjsip

I have the iOS VoIP call Application. Everything works fine when App is in foreground and background. But When I terminate the application I deleted accounts.

When Incoming call arrives VoIP notification is received but registration process is not even started so caller gets **403 forbidden** and call gets disconnected. I deleted account and stopped pjsip manually when App is in background and checked for incoming call it works fine. But in terminated state why registration process is not even take place when Incoming call arrives.

Any hint will be helpful for me. Thanks in advance.